# w7 -> VB6 error "User-defined type not defined"

Tags: windows-7, vb6

I receive error "User-defined type not defined" when trying to compile a VB6 programme.The statement "Public fMainForm As frmMain" is highlighted by the compiler. This programme has previously compiled without error.

My code is

```
Public fMainForm As frmMain
Public commonSQl, commonDSN, commonPealNo, commonDove, _
commonGridRefE, commonGridRefN As String
Public commonDate As Date
Public commonShowUnringable As Boolean
Public IsOpen As Integer



Sub Main()
    Dim fLogin As New frmLogin
    commonDSN = ""
    fLogin.Show vbModal
    Isloaded = -1
    If Not fLogin.OK Then
    'Login Failed so exit app
    End
    End If
    Unload fLogin


    frmSplash.Show
    frmSplash.Refresh
    Set fMainForm = New frmMain
    Load fMainForm
    Unload frmSplash


    fMainForm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to reduce your example to the fMainForm variable only, remove all the rest; make a new test project with just this. And add an Option Explicit at the Top of each file (you declare an IsOpen, but I see an Isloaded being referenced).

Comment: Thank you. Still fails with just the fMainForm variable. Changed variable type to source - works ok. Looks like VB is not loading definition for frmMain object?

Comment: and frmMain is?

Comment: it is the start up object of the project

Comment: what does that mean? Is it a form? Is this VB6 (because New frmMain isn't allowed in VB6)

Comment: yes it is VB6 . Why is it not allowed? There are several examples of sample vb6 code where it is used

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have frmMain form added to your project. Please check that it is available.

[image]